# Query count in .net

Tags: .net, sql, profiling

I'd like to do something similar to [Queries count for page in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116960/queries-count-for-page-in-asp-net-mvc) - namely count the number of SQL queries executed in a particular request, and time them.

The difference is, I don't have a standard method that all SQL queries are routed through - I need a method for intercepting all calls and tracking them. Is there some kind of hook I could use, or do you know of a tutorial for using the .NET profiler to record calls to and from a method, or even another method?

I don't want to use the SQL Server profiler library for this - I want something built into .NET so there are no dependencies. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp) for this.

Comment: I'm fairly familiar with PostSharp but wouldn't really know where to start when it comes to intercepting calls to the BCL. Do you have any more pointers?

Comment: I am assuming you would trace your own methods that are calling BCL.

Comment: I would like to be able to trace other peoples methods too! I guess the CLR Profiler API would be the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) allows you to use Event Tracing for Windows to pick up the SQL Queries as well. You may be able to automate this, but I'm not sure.